# Android won't send data to PHP using JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, send

I am trying create an android app that can send data to a PHP server using JSON. I followed this guide: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ and here is my Android code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText userName;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.35/workspace/sosapp/db_connect.php";    

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Edit Text
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);

        // Send button
        Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        // button click event
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = userName.getText().toString();

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));

                // getting JSON Object
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

            } 
        }); 

    }
}
```

As for my PHP code:

```
  function insert($var1) {

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO report (name) VALUES ('$var1')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database;
    $msg = "Message received.";
    } else {
    $msg = "Not received.";
    }
return ($msg);
}

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
   $name = $_POST['name']);
   insert($name);   
} else {
   echo "No input.";
}
```

I keep getting No input. I run the android app (on my phone connected to the computer), then  I refresh the PHP site but I keep getting no input. The android app does not send the data. Can someone pls help? THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: you want to send json String to server. as jsonObject or JsonArray?

Comment: make sure you are able to access the web service from browser...

Comment: Yes I can access the address from the phone's browser. I would like to send it as an array.

Comment: @user1994644 can you paste your makeHttpRequest method here

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, it's the JSONParser class of the tutorial. It checks for

```
method == "POST"
```

which is wrong.
Change this to

```
method.equals("POST")
```

and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Android Http is only Background running  allow

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText userName;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.35/workspace/sosapp/db_connect.php";    

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Edit Text
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);

        // Send button
        Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        // button click event
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = userName.getText().toString();

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));

                // getting JSON Object

            Thread httpthread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

          JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);


  runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
             public void run() {
                 // ui working  ex)textview.setText("test");


             }
        });

            }
        });

httpthread.start();
            } 
        }); 

    }
}
```